# How to write a PIVOT query from this SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following SQL Query running on SQL Server 2014 (Thanks Thorsten!). Currently, I export the output into Excel 2013 and run my pivot table from there. I understand there is a way to write an SQL PIVOT query so that the output is exactly the same as the one in Excel.

My SQL Query stands as follows:

```
SELECT 
  b.PropertyCode,
  x.[ReservationStayID],
  x.[Nights Spent],
  x.[MTH],
  x.[Rate],
  x.CreatedOn,
  x.[DateOfArrival],
  x.[DateOfDeparture]

 FROM GuestNameInfo a
 JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT 
     ReservationStayID,
     datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar) as [MTH],
     count(*) AS [Nights Spent],
     avg(RateAmount) as [Rate],
     min(CreatedOn) as CreatedOn,
     min(StayDate) as [DateOfArrival],
     max(StayDate) as [DateOfDeparture]
   FROM ReservationStayDate
  GROUP BY ReservationStayID, datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar)
 ) x ON x.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID

 WHERE a.PrimaryGuest = '+'

 AND NOT a.DepartureDate < '2014-11-01'

 AND NOT (b.ReservationStatus = 'CANCELED' OR b.ReservationStatus = 'NOSHOW')

 AND NOT b.MarketSegmentCode = 'COMP'
```

I need the SQL PIVOT code to give me the following output:

```
PropertyCode     October 2014   November 2014  ....... April 2015

  AB                256              154        ......  247
  SD                143              315        ......  189
```

The values inside the above output are the sum of Nights Spent.

The output of the SQL Query as it currently stands is as follows:

```
PropertyCode     ReservationStayId    Nights Spent   MTH            Rate ......Date of Departure
AB                  5123                  12         November 2014   125.30 ....  2014-11-25
```

Comment: Add the Output of your query.

Comment: Please add output of your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first , put yout query result in to temp table:

```
SELECT 
  b.PropertyCode,
  x.[ReservationStayID],
  x.[Nights Spent],
  x.[MTH],
  x.[Rate],
  x.CreatedOn,
  x.[DateOfArrival],
  x.[DateOfDeparture]

 INTO #tmp /*HERE*/

 FROM GuestNameInfo a
 JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT 
     ReservationStayID,
     datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar) as [MTH],
     count(*) AS [Nights Spent],
     avg(RateAmount) as [Rate],
     min(CreatedOn) as CreatedOn,
     min(StayDate) as [DateOfArrival],
     max(StayDate) as [DateOfDeparture]
   FROM ReservationStayDate
  GROUP BY ReservationStayID, datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar)
 ) x ON x.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID

 WHERE a.PrimaryGuest = '+'

 AND NOT a.DepartureDate < '2014-11-01'

 AND NOT (b.ReservationStatus = 'CANCELED' OR b.ReservationStatus = 'NOSHOW')

 AND NOT b.MarketSegmentCode = 'COMP'
```

Then select only columns neded for pivot (in to global temporary with ##):

```
SELECT PropertyCode,[Nights Spent] as Nights,MTH
INTO ##temporary_for_pivot
FROM #tmp
```

Then Select values for columnnames in to temporary (you can here make order for columns...):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_for_columnames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp_for_columnames
SELECT DISTINCT MTH
INTO #temp_for_columnames
FROM ##temporary_for_pivot
```

Then create dynamic pivot script (because u dont known number of columns) and run it:

```
DECLARE @COLUMNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @COLUMNS = 
STUFF(CAST((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(MTH) FROM #temp_for_columnames FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),1,1,'')

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @cmd = 'SELECT PropertyCode, '+@COLUMNS+'
            FROM ##temporary_for_pivot
            PIVOT ( SUM(Nights) FOR MTH IN ('+@COLUMNS+')) x'

EXEC(@cmd)
```

Done :)

Comment: Thanks. Should I run these batch of codes separately? Or can I just paste them all together and run the whole script?
Also, in code batch 2, should I replace the 'tempdb..#temp_for_columnames' by the names of the month I wish to output as columns?

Comment: You can run it together.IN tempdb..#temp_for_columnames is column names (November 2014 , December 2014) , why you want replace them ? I dont understand. But if you run it together it is working.

Comment: In tempdb..#temp_for_columnames you can give clausule ORDER BY... For example order by YEAR() from date column... I mean Your order in this table is order in final table .  for example colimn1-November, column2-December... Or other order column1-december, column2-november

Comment: Fantastic! Works great! My only issue is it does not display the months column in a chronological order. Is that easily corrected? If not, I can live with it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes ofc, you can make chronological order in to the table #temp_for_columnames. In code batch 2.

Comment: Thanks Matej. I tried ORDER BY MTH but it did not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: MTH is string value, you must identify part of month and part of year and convert it  in to the date format, or numeric format. For example: November = 11, and year is 2014: CLAUSULE ORDER BY YEAR ,MONTH